# Large XLSX file in Nodejs returning empty data

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I have built a web crawler that goes to a page and downloads a large inventory xlsx file. I am attempting to read the file, create a id out of specific cell values in the file and then save it to a csv.

Usually I have no issue doing this, but with the particular file, it is very large. When attempting to use node-xlsx, excellJs, and XLSX npm packages all do the same thing. They just return empty for the data, even though the file definately exists.

I've tested the same code on smaller xlsx files and it works, but the large file just returns an empty array for the sheets variable.

```js
           const inventoryFile = readFileSync('./tmp/inventory.xlsx');
const inventoryWorkbook = xlsx.parse(inventoryFile)
console.log({inventoryWorkbook})  //returns [];
```

I also tried using a stream and still when parsed it returns an empty array even though I can see the data buffers logging.

```js
let sheet:string = '';
const stream = createReadStream(`./tmp/${timeInSecs}/nb-inventory-${fileDate}.xlsx`)
const buffers: Buffer[] = [];
stream.on('data',(data: Buffer)=>{ 
   console.log({data})
   buffers.push(data); 
});
stream.on('end',()=>{
   const buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
   console.log({buffer})
   const sheets = xlsx.parse(buffer, {})
   console.log({sheets}); //returns []               
})
```

Is there anyway to get around this limit?

Thanks.